# How to perform StratifiedGroupKFold based on ID that should not be part of training?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation, grid-search

I am trying to perform logistic regression using `StratifiedGroupKFold` as shown in the following code.

```
grid={'C':np.logspace(-3,3,7)}
grkf_cv = StratifiedGroupKFold(n_splits=10)
id_ls = X_train_df['ID'].to_list()  

log_reg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=100, random_state=42)
logreg_cv = GridSearchCV(log_reg, grid, cv=grkf_cv, scoring='roc_auc')
logreg_cv.fit(X_train_df, y_train_df, groups=id_ls)
```

This causes a conflict as the model is training with the group ID which is incorrect and it appears as a feature. My issue is I need to pass `id_ls` with `X_train_df` (which contains the ID). I am not sure how splits would be performed if `X_train_df` did not contain the ID.

I can drop the ID from `X_train_df` and then train but I do not think the splits would be performed based on groups.

Is there a way around this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to run it after droping the IDs from X_train?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example in sklearn documentation (found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold.html)), you can see that they define the `groups` parameter separately, without it ever being a part of the training dataset.

I am assuming this is because the `groups` parameter does not have to be checked against a column, as it already contains the group label for each sample **in order**.

It makes sense, the function knows that the first row of `X_train` has group id the first element of `id_ls` (which you are passing at the `groups` parameter), the second row is matched to the second element of the list etc.